# How can I automate adding a post-hoc comparison to my statistics table in Markdown? I would prefer using the tableby function in the arsenal package

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating a descriptive statistics table for large data sets built into Markdown, so I prefer using the arsenal package that I can adjust the output of and feed into kable. I like that it can handle continuous and categorical variables without me having to separate them and it will automatically decide on the appropriate test.  I want to add some columns for post-hoc comparisons, but I'm not sure how to do this. My current code:

```
tab1<-tableby(Cluster~., data = ModelData, digits.pct = 1, digits.count = 1, numeric.stats = c("meansd"))
sd<-as.data.frame(summary(tab1))
pvalscript<- sd$'p value'
pvalscript[pvalscript == "< 0.001"]<- "0"
pvals<-as.numeric(pvalscript)
pvals[is.na(pvals)]<-1
colnames(sd)[1]<-'Variable'
options(kableExtra.auto_format = T)
colnames(sd)[length(colnames(sd))]<-'p_value'
#bold the first column of anything that has a p-value
#haspvalue<- sd$`p value`!=""
sd%>% mutate(p_value =cell_spec(p_value, "html", background = ifelse(pvals<0.05, "yellow", "")))%>%
 kable(format = "html", escape = F)%>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"))%>%
  scroll_box(width = "100%", height = "500px")
```

Comment: I loaded the arsenal package, but can't find any data anywhere called "ModelData". This might be why nobody has provided an answer yet.

Comment: I might be able to tell if I could run the code, but I'm unclear as to what post-hoc comparisons you need to run. It looks like you get a p-value per group (grouped by cluster?) but I can't tell how you're getting it, and what it's a p-value *of*. Either way, I'd personally look to do it with dplyr's `group_by()` and `summarize()`, or maybe `do()` if necessary.